# PHP добавить параграфы

Tags: php, строки

Допустим есть строка, где вперемешку есть текст как заключенный в p теги, так и нет:

```
раз два 
<p>три  <a href='#'>четыре</a> пять</p> 
<img src="#">шесть <strong>семь</strong>
<p>восемь</p>
девять десять
```

Может у кого есть пример как весь текст не заключенный в p, в него заключить:

```
<p>раз два</p>
<p>три  <a href='#'>четыре</a> пять</p> 
<p><img src="#">шесть <strong>семь</strong></p>
<p>восемь</p>
<p>девять десять</p>
```

Текст организован без символов перевода строки.

Пробовал пример https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5961217/how-do-i-surround-all-text-pieces-with-paragraph-tags?answertab=active#tab-top (nl2p_html) но он съедает все вложенные теги.

Comment: "*Текст организован без символов перевода строки*" - во-первых, у вас это не так, переводы строк есть. Во-вторых, по каким тогда критериям предполагается выделать фрагменты для заключения в параграфы?

Comment: Примеры с переводом строки я привел для наглядности. А критерий - отсутствие тега p (думал может у кого есть хитрая регулярка).

Comment: Что значит "отсутствие тега p"? Во всём оригинальном тексте "Войны и мира" нет ни одного тега p, это, получается, один большой абзац? Или нужно через каждое слово его вставлять?

Comment: Да, в моем случае - это один большой параграф, а если в тексте до или после был этот тег, то в тег надо засунуть конкретный кусок текста (вместе с другими тегами, которые могут в нем быть).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ну что-то типо этого:

```
$pattern = '/(^|<\\/[^>]*p>)(.*)(<[^>]*p>|$)/isU';
$replacement = '$1<p>$2</p>$3';
$subject = 'ваша строка';
echo preg_replace($pattern, $replacement, $subject, -1 );
```

Comment: Спасибо, то что нужно.